# HTTP Status 404 - /OpenKM --Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu),

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-14.04, openkm

good day

can anyone help after installing openkm on ubuntu 14.04 ,im getting this below error:

**HTTP Status 404 - /OpenKM**

**type Status report**

**message /OpenKM**

**description The requested resource is not available.**

**Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)**

Comment: No custom code = not programming related. No steps to reproduce. Those are two reasons to close this question. Please either find a proper site in the stackexchange network or edit your question with your custom code and steps to reproduce.

Comment: okay let me send the logs

Comment: Logs won't make it more on topic. See [help/on-topic] for what's on topic for stackoverflow. Hint: It's about programming issues, not about configuring or setting up any software.